# strange text in internet explorer dialogs and buttons

Tags: display, internet-explorer

A user is having problems with internet explorer that I can't figure out...

[image]

Any idea what is wrong with the text and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When does this occur?  Only when a security dialog pops up?

Try updating video card drivers from the Video card vendors website.  It may be a faulty video card itself and be in need of replacement.  You could also try booting up with a LiveCD of Windows or Linux and see if the problem persists.  If so, it's probably hardware.